# Syntax error while using psycopg2.copy_expert

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) to call PostgreSQL `COPY` command from my programs written in Python, and so far I have used `copy_from` function in that package to achieve this. As I understand, in recent versions qualified names for tables, that is, `scheman_name.table_name` are no more authorized while using `copy_from` for security reasons (SQL injection). According to what I read on their Github page, apparently [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) is henceforth the way to go for qualified names. I tried to adapt my program accordingly but I get a syntax error. Here I provide a test case.

Let's say that this is my table (assuming that `dev_schema` is an already existing schema):

```
create table dev_schema.testtab(numval integer not null);
```

And our data file to import into this table:
**Data.txt**

```
100
120
200
800
500
```

To import the above file into the table directly via `psql`, all I have to do is running the following command in `psql` prompt:

```
 \copy dev_schema.testtab from 'D:/Data.txt' with (format CSV, NULL '', delimiter '|', quote '"');
```

My purpose was to translate the above into a Python program using `psycopg2.copy_expert`.

And here is my program:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql


def main():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="testdb",
        user="dev_user",
        password="Here I write my password",
        host="localhost",
        port=5432
    )
    #
    # Create a cursor
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    #
    #
    # Importing the data file
    filepath = "D:/Data.txt"
    with open(
        file=filepath,
        mode="r",
        encoding="UTF-8"
    ) as file_desc:
        option_values = [
            "format CSV",
            "NULL ''",
            "delimiter '|'",
            "quote '\"'"
        ]
        copy_options = sql.SQL(', ').join(
            sql.Identifier(n) for n in option_values
        )
        cursor.copy_expert(
            sql=sql.SQL(
                "copy {} from stdin with ({})"
            ).format(
                sql.Identifier("dev_schema", "testtab"),
                copy_options
            ),
            file=file_desc
        )

    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when I run this program I get the following error message:

```
cursor.copy_expert(
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ERROR:  option « format CSV » not recognized
LINE 1: copy "dev_schema"."testtab" from stdin with ("format CSV", "...
```

But I don't see what's the problem with `CSV` option as it works pretty well when I use directly `\copy` in `psql` prompt.

Could you kindly make some clarification?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Based on Adrian Klaver's comment I changed my code accordingly by including directly as a string all options at the end but now I get a new error message:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ERROR : Syntax error on or near   'dev_schema'  
LINE 1: copy Identifier('dev_schema', 'testtab') from stdin with (fo...
```

Here is the new version of my code:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql


def main():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="testdb",
        user="dev_user",
        password="Here I write my password",
        host="localhost",
        port=5432
    )
    #
    # Create a cursor
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    #
    #
    # Importing the data file
    filepath = "D:/Data.txt"
    with open(
        file=filepath,
        mode="r",
        encoding="UTF-8"
    ) as file_desc:
        option_values = "".join(
            [
                "format CSV, ",
                "NULL '', ",
                "delimiter '|', ",
                "quote '\"',"
            ]
        )
        cursor.copy_expert(
            sql=sql.SQL("".join(
                [
                    "copy {} from stdin with (",
                    option_values,
                    ")"
                ]).format(sql.Identifier("dev_schema", "testtab"))
            ),
            file=file_desc
        )

    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The options are not `identifiers`, the double quotes are what is causing the issue.

Comment: Should have added you will to either just hard code it into the string or use `sql.SQL`. Note `sql.SQL` will not do any escaping.

Comment: I changed the code based on your suggestion. Now I get a new error message. You can view the new version of my code in the EDIT above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General tip. Assign a composed query to a variable and print it to see what is wrong.

```py
        copy_cmd = sql.SQL(
            "copy {} from stdin with ({})"
        ).format(
            sql.Identifier("dev_schema", "testtab"),
            copy_options
        )
        print(copy_cmd.as_string(connection))
```

Of course, `copy_options` should be built as plain text, not a list of identifiers:

```py
    with open(
        file=filepath,
        mode="r",
        encoding="UTF-8"
    ) as file_desc:
        option_values = [
            "format CSV",
            "NULL ''",
            "delimiter '|'",
            "quote '\"'"
        ]
        copy_options = sql.SQL(', '.join(
            n for n in option_values)
        )
        copy_cmd = sql.SQL(
            "copy {} from stdin with ({})"
        ).format(
            sql.Identifier("dev_schema", "testtab"),
            copy_options
        )
        # print(copy_cmd.as_string(connection))
        cursor.copy_expert(
            sql=copy_cmd,
            file=file_desc
        )

    connection.commit() # !!!
    connection.close()
```

Do not forget to commit!

Comment: PostgreSQL is by default in auto commit mode. I tried what you suggested, that is, printing the generated string. Indeed I have a very strange result:


copy Identifier('dev_schema', 'testtab') from stdin with (SQL('f, o, r, m, a, t,  , C, S, V, N, U, L, L,  , \', \', d, e, l, i, m, i, t, e, r,  , \', |, \', q, u, o, t, e,  , \', ", \''))

Comment: You did not try my code, just copy and paste. Commit is necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right! I had forgotten to convert copy options to a simple Python list and not a string join list. Thank you very much for your time and your help.

Comment: Not a matter, good luck.